# Looping through removing and adding object attributes

Tags: javascript, object

I have a function passing me an instance in which im tryin to display 4 different html elements and only 1 can be visible at a time.

```
function(instance, context) {

  var blank = $('#blank');
  var good = $('#good');
  var mediocre = $('#mediocre');
  var bad = $('#bad');

  instance.canvas.append(blank);
}
```

Then another function passing me updated values. But this loop only works for the very first iteration and I cannot figure out why

```
function(instance, properties, context) {

  var strength = properties.strength;
  var red = properties.red_shows_until;
  var yellow = properties.yellow_shows_until

  if (strength > 0 && strength < red) {
    blank.remove();
    instance.canvas.append(bad);

  } else if (strength >= red && strength < yellow) {
    bad.remove();
    instance.canvas.append(mediocre);
  } else if (strength >= yellow) {
    yellow.remove();
    instance.canvas.append(good);
  } else {
    good.remove();
    instance.canvas.append(blank);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the loop in the code? You just have `if/else`, that doesn't repeat.

Comment: Since you use `else if`, it only executes the block for the first condition that matches.

Comment: `append(element)` doesn't make a  copy of the element. If you append the same element   in multiple places, it will only be in the last place.

Comment: Your functions have no names, so there's obviously some code missing. Also it's not clear what `instance.canvas` is, but you're calling `append` on it and passing a jQuery object to that, so hopefully it's also a jQuery object. `blank` is declared in one function and referenced in another; you should be getting some errors about that.